How to assign the closest order to a truck within the seize block?
I'm working on a delivery simulation model in AnyLogic, based on the airport example. My model consists of four agent types:
Hub
Truck (parameter: client)
House
Order (parameter: customer)
The process works as follows:

The House agent creates an Order when it switches from normalWork to waiting.
The Order includes a customer parameter that refers to the House that initiated the order.
The Order is processed using blocks from the Process Modeling Library. The seize block assigns a Truck to the Order by setting the truck's client parameter to the order's customer with this logic:

((Truck) unit).client = agent.customer;

However, I would like to adjust the model so that the Truck delivers to the closest Order. The existing seize block allows an Order to seize the closest Truck, but I need the reverse: I want the Truck to always pick the closest Order from the queue after each delivery.
My idea: I was considering placing a queue in front of the Truck to sort the orders based on proximity to the truck, but I’m not sure how to compare agents based on their distances.
The challenge I'm facing: Since the Order is an agent type, I struggle to access each order individually to calculate distances between the truck and each order. This is making it difficult to implement the comparison logic I need.
Has anyone worked on agent comparison in AnyLogic for this kind of scenario? Is there a quick fix or a workaround for sorting orders by distance to the truck? Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.
Attached:Here's a screenshot of the current processing model for reference

Consider switching trucks and orders: Not one seizing the other, but vice versa.
Else, switch to a purely agent-based setup (see the SC step-by-step- tutorial in the help)
Else, write a function that takes all orders and sorts them by distance. Google "Comparator" to learn how to sort objects by a characteristic
Tons of options, none is better or worse, it all depends on your actual model and skill level (above is sorted from easiest to hardest)
